# Is it possible to wikipedia-ize one's own site?

Tags: backlinks, website-promotion

My website lists the all-time winners of several prestigious awards presented for books (Pulitzer, etc.), movies (Oscars, etc.), and music (Grammies, etc.).

I would like a link to my site to appear at the bottom of wikipedia articles (external links) about those awards.

Is this possible? Anybody, supposedly, can edit existing Wikipedia articles, but is such "self promotion" frowned upon or even santioned? IOW, would it be a waste of time, as such an addition would be immediately redacted/removed/elided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you would link spamming Wikipedia which is very frowned upon. Wikipedia actually frowns upon having External Links sections in their pages and when they do exist they are limited to important  directly related to the article (i.e. the company's home page, etc). Your site would not meet these standards and would be removed if they were added. I would also suspect if you tried to add them often enough your site would ultimately be banned from Wikipedia making it impossible to have your link placed there should it ever meet their guidelines as an acceptable link.